# Java script: How to mask first five digits of nine digit number using regex?

Tags: javascript

Ex: 123456789
Regex Result: #####6789

If it is 10 digit or more than that it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is a pretty straightforward problem.

Comment: You don't even need regex for that

Comment: `var masked_numer = your_number.slice(5)`

Comment: Looks like you didn't event bother to search a bit for a solution. No Regex needed for that. Hint : check the String.prototype functions

Answer (score 3):

Why is regex needed for this basic string problem?

```js
function mask(val){
  result = (val.length === 9) ? "#####" + val.substr(5, val.length-1) : val;
  console.log(result);
}

mask("123456789");
mask("1234567890");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your number is always preceded by a letter or a whitespace:

```
 myString.replace(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z\s])(\d{5})(\d{4})([a-zA-Z\s])",g), "$1#####$3$4")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and adjust the length after adding the prefix.

```js
function getMasked(string) {
    return string.length < 10
        ? ('#####' + string.slice(5)).slice(0, string.length)
        : string;
}

console.log(getMasked('123456789'));
console.log(getMasked('1234567890'));
console.log(getMasked('1'));
```

Comment: The mask is only supposed to be applied when there are 9 chars. Any other amount and no masking occurs.

Comment: my field is string field. In the string field it has letters and numbers. Ex: "123456789 this is customer id". String looks like this. So that's why i wanted to take only 9 digit number and mask first five digits

Comment: you need to add some use cases, otherwise it's just speculation, what you need.